# How to update a text file based on values within it

Tags: java, file, csv, flat-file

I want to edit certain values(a row values) of a csv file based on a specific value of that row (an id). I am able to read and write (append) the values in it but cannot figure out how to edit and delete them.

Here is a small fragment of code for what I am doing for reading the file and appending values:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.csv", true);
try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.csv");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String strLine;              
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = strLine.split(",");
        if (fields[1].equals("value") {
            fields[1] = "different value";
        }
        writer.append(fields);
    }
    catch(...)
}
```

But I can't work out how to write the values back into the same spot in the file.

Comment: To edit and delete, you need to read the entire file (storing it in some format, ie ArrayList of objects), clearing the .csv file, and rewriting it back out with the modified values.

Comment: By clearing do you mean deleting it? Or in any other way.

Comment: Deleting it would be easier, you can simply do this by creating an instance of your file, (File file = new file(<path>); and then calling file.delete

Comment: You can do it by using `writer.print("");`. Then loop through your rows and append as you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't open a single file for both reading and writing at the same time. You need to read the file and close it before opening it for writing.

The potential solutions are:

- Write the output to a different file and then replace the original when complete
- Keep all the output in internal variables then, once you've finished reading, close the file and reopen it for writing.